# How to use a whole list as a parameter in a Python function?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to make a function in Python that would take a list as input, and return a multiple of all the numbers in the list:

```
def multiply_list(numbers):
    product = 1

    for int in numbers:
        product = product*numbers[int]

    return product
```

I tried testing it by using:

```
ints = [1, 7, 3, 4]

print(multiply_list(ints))
```

However, I get a "list index out of range"-exception. For some reason I can't figure out why I am getting this exception. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: If you use `for int in numbers`, `int` will be the *value* of the current number, not the *index*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for int in numbers:
        product = product*int
```

int is the actual item, not an index

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
def multiply_list(numbers):
  product = 1    
  return [ product * x for x in numbers]

ints = [1, 7, 3, 4]

print(multiply_list(ints))
```

Comment: You're just returning a copy of the input list.